# C, Segmentation failed with struct pointer in func

Tags: c, function, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to create linked list in C and I created add_to_front func to add elements with recursion. But `if (h -> next == NULL)` raises Segmentation failed error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H91N7.png)
I tried to check adress in h param and it is different from the one I give to this function.
I thought the problem is that I allocated not enough memory, but that didn`t helped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct list
{
    char* name;
    char symbol;
    double weight;
    struct list *next;
} list;

list* create_list(char* name, char symbol, double weight)
{
    list* head = malloc(sizeof(list) + 1000);
    head -> next = NULL;
    head -> name = name;
    head -> symbol = symbol;
    head -> weight = weight;
    return head;
}

void add_to_front(char* name, char symbol, double weight, list* h)
{
    printf("%p", h);
    if (h -> next == NULL)
    {
        h -> next = create_list(name, symbol, weight);
    }
    else
    {
        return add_to_front(name, symbol, weight, h -> next);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char* name;
    char symbol;
    double weight;
    printf("Enter element's name: ");
    scanf("%10s", name);
    printf("Enter element's symbol: ");
    scanf("%2c", &symbol);
    printf("Enter element's weight: ");
    scanf("%f", &weight);
    list* head = create_list(name, symbol, weight);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter element's name: ");
        scanf("%10s", name);
        printf("Enter element's symbol: ");
        scanf("%2c", &symbol);
        printf("Enter element's weight: ");
        scanf("%f", &weight);
        printf("%p", head);
        add_to_front(name, symbol, weight, head);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(list) + 1000)`, why add `1000` bytes to the allocation? That's just a waste of space.

Comment: I believe the segmentation fault is due to ```name``` variable in ```list``` struct. You are passing a ```char``` pointer around.

Comment: Change your code to allocate separate memory for ```name``` in each ```create_list```.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code.

For example the pointer `name` declared in `main` like

```
char* name;
```

is uninitialized and hense does not point to a memory where a string can be stored. As a result this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%10s", name);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

To use such a call of `scanf` you need to declare a character array at least like

```
char name[11];
```

Consequently in the structure declaration it is reasonable also to declare a character array as its data member

```
typedef struct list
{
    char name[11];
    char symbol;
    double weight;
    struct list *next;
} list;
```

The variable `weight` is declared as having the type `double`

```
double weight;
```

But you are using an incorrect conversion specifier in this call of scanf

```
scanf("%f", &weight);
      ^^^^
```

You have to write

```
scanf("%lf", &weight);
      ^^^^
```

To read a single character there is no need to use the length modifier `2`

```
scanf("%2c", &symbol);
       ^^^
```

Just write

```
scanf( " %c", &symbol);
       ^^^^
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters in the input buffer.

The function `create_list` should be declared like

```
list* create_list( const char* name, char symbol, double weight);
```

That is the parameter `name` should be declared with the qualifier `const` becuase passed strings are not changed within the function.

Also within the function instead of assigning pointers like

```
head -> name = name;
```

you need to copy the string pointed to by the parameter `name` in the data member of the structure `head-<name` using standard function `strcpy`declared in header `<string.h>`  (provided that the data member is declared as having the array type shown above)

```
strcpy( head -> name, name );
```

If the data member has the pointer type as shown in your original code then you need to allocate dynamically memory for the stored string as for example

```
head -> name = malloc( strlen( name ) + 1 );
```

and again to copy the source string in the allocated memory using the same call of `strcpy` shown above.

Using the magic number `1000` in this call of `malloc`

```
list* head = malloc(sizeof(list) + 1000);
```

does not make sense. Just write

```
list* head = malloc(sizeof(list));
```

The function `add_to_front` may be called in general with the pointer `head` equal to `NULL`. So this statement

```
if (h -> next == NULL)
```

where a null pointer can be used can invoke undefined behavior

The return statement with an expression of the type `void` (it is the return type of the function)

```
return add_to_front(name, symbol, weight, h -> next);
```

is invalid.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
list * add_to_front( const char* name, char symbol, double weight, list* h)
{
    if ( h == NULL)
    {
        return create_list(name, symbol, weight);
    }
    else
    {
        h->next = add_to_front(name, symbol, weight, h -> next);
        return h;
    }
}
```

and called in `main` like

```
head = add_to_front(name, symbol, weight, head);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code have:

```
char* name;
scanf("%10s", name);
```

The pointer variable `name` is not initialized. It will point to an *indeterminate* location. Any attempt to dereference this pointer (which `scanf` will do) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Writing to wherever this pointer is pointing likely causes the crash.

Change `name` to be an array instead:

```
char name[11];
```

---

Also note that the assignment

```
head -> name = name;
```

will *not* copy the string. It will instead copy the *pointer*. So after the assignment, you have two pointers pointing to the same location.

If other parts of the code changes the contents of the string, then all nodes will appear to change as well.

Define the `list` member variable as an array as well, and use `strcpy` to copy it.